# IsValid() is not triggered in MVC model validation using RegularExpressionAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a model where I would like to check if the string is valid.

I first check if the string only contain numbers, this part works. After this I would like to do another check to see if the sum of the numbers are correct.

The last part does not work. **IsValid() is never triggered**.

Model:

```
    [ValidImei]
    string Imei { get; set; }
```

Attribute validation

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ValidImeiAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{

    public ValidImeiAttribute() : base(@"^\d+$")
    {
        ErrorMessage = ValidationMessage.InvalidImeiOnlyNumbersAllowed;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {

        // THIS CODE IS NEVER TRIGGERED?
        var isRegexValid = base.IsValid(value);
        if (!isRegexValid)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var imei = value as string;

        var validator = NinjectWebCommon.Kernel.Get<IImeiValidator>();

        string errorMessage;
        return validator.IsValid(imei, out errorMessage);

    }
}
```

Global, application start

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(ValidImeiAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```